# Plotting bivariate Gaussians in R

Tags: r, gaussian

I have two classes, C1 and C2, both of which are described by bivariate Gaussians with means at (0,0) and (1,3) and covariances I and 2I. Priors of C1 and C2 are 0.4 and 0.6 respectively.

I have to plot 10 points of C1 and 15 points of C2 on a scatter plot in R for the later purposes of calculating some classification boundaries, so this is not really a crucial part of the problem, I just need to know how to do it so I can start.

I've tried looking it up the documentation online but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out

```
library('MASS')
sz_1<-10;
sz_2<-15;    df<-rbind(data.frame(mvrnorm(n=sz_1,mu=c(0,0),Sigma=diag(2))),data.frame(mvrnorm(n=sz_2,mu=c(1,3),Sigma=2*diag(2))));
plot(df,xlab="x-value",ylab="y-value",col="purple",main="scatter-plot of mixed gaussians");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(mvtnorm)
l=3
sigma <- matrix(c(l,2,2,2*l), ncol=2)
C2 <- rmvnorm(n=15, mean=c(1,3), sigma=sigma)
C1 <- rmvnorm(n=10, mean=c(0,0), sigma=sigma)

 plot(C1, xlim=range( c(C1[,1],C2[,1]) ) , ylim=range( c(C1[,2],C2[,2]) ) , col="red")
 points(C2,  col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: This will probably work but I don't have that library downloaded and the other answer worked without having to download a library. I really do appreciate your answer though, thank you

Comment: They are probably the same function, ya' know?

Comment: Actually not the same. mvtnorm::rmvnorm has more methods.

Answer (score 0):

The dmnorm function you found there will generate the 2d Gaussian you're after, but there is still the issue of the two separate classes. For that use your priors 0.4 and 0.6. You could use a Bernoulli or runif()<p to choose the class of each point generated sequentially.
 That should do it.